# Не могу вывести значение в консоль

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Есть авто-заполнение `Jquery ui` .
Находится в скрипте

```
var cities=[

{value:"40,450381.49,758641",label:"20 Yanvar"},
{value:"40,541181.49,662469",label:"20 Yanvar (Ceyranbatan)"},
{value:"40,431829.49,744946",label:"20 Yanvar (Hokmeli)"},
{value:"40,496519.49,853885",label:"20 Yanvar (Mehdiabad)"},
{value:"40,536043.49,781115",label:"20 Yanvar (Novxani)"},
{value:"40,528399.49,712136",label:"20 Yanvar (Saray)"},
{value:"40,448343.49,752389",label:"28 May "},
{value:"40,532444.49,844124",label:"28 May (Fatmayi)"},
{value:"40,4608.49,76938",label:"28 May (Masazir)"}

]
```

Хочу вывестити в консоль данные

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source:cities,
        minLength:2,
        select:function(event,ui){
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            var b = $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            console.log(b);


        }
    });
});
```

Не получается,а когда хочу в алерт пишет Object object, хотя в input передает значение.Как бть 
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log($(this).val());`

http://api.jquery.com/val/

`$(...).val()` без параметров возвращает значение в инпуте,

`$(...).val(...)`с параметром устанавливает значение в инпуте и возвращает объект-обертку jQuery

*Update*

Чтобы ограничить количество выпадающих строк, используем событие `response` плагина `autocomplete`:

```
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source:cities,
        minLength:2,
        response:function(event, ui){
          if (ui.content.length > 10)
            ui.content.splice(10);
        },
        select:function(event,ui){
          ...
```

Comment: а можно чтоб он показывал 10 элементов ,а то у меня в массиве около 4000 тысяч и за раз он может показать около 300

Comment: @elik объясните, пожалуйста, кто такой "он" и где показывал

Comment: когда в input пишу текст то снизу inputa полей автоподсказок бывает много .Так как находит очень много значений .Можно ли показывать лишь 10  значений

Comment: @elik Понял. Смотрите ответ - свойство `response` в инициализации `autocomplete`.

Comment: спасибо Большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cities=[

{value:"40,450381.49,758641",label:"20 Yanvar"},
{value:"40,541181.49,662469",label:"20 Yanvar (Ceyranbatan)"},
{value:"40,431829.49,744946",label:"20 Yanvar (Hokmeli)"},
{value:"40,496519.49,853885",label:"20 Yanvar (Mehdiabad)"},
{value:"40,536043.49,781115",label:"20 Yanvar (Novxani)"},
{value:"40,528399.49,712136",label:"20 Yanvar (Saray)"},
{value:"40,448343.49,752389",label:"28 May "},
{value:"40,532444.49,844124",label:"28 May (Fatmayi)"},
{value:"40,4608.49,76938",label:"28 May (Masazir)"}

]

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source:cities,
        minLength:2,
        select:function(event,ui){
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            var b = $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            console.log(b.val());


        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="tags">
```